# Could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit' For FacebookSDK after using of CocoaPods manager

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

For first time I decided to use CocoaPods dependency manager in my current Swift project but now can't build it. I'm getting [this errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjrJG.png) - Could not build module 'FacebookSDK'

Here is my [Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD2iJ.png)

So I will be very thankful for any advice how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: And here is my [build settings for modules](https://upx.cz/B6s) in XCode 7.1

Comment: Please include the images into your question. External references can get unavailable with time.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I tried described workarounds in that thread but nothing from that worked for me. I think that my problem is related to using CocoaPods dependency manager becuase when I'm not using Cocoa Pods and I munually add libraries dependency I build my project without problems.

Comment: It's very possible that it's a dependency issue i.e. Version X of some library depends on Version Y of library A but you've required a different version in the podfile.

Comment: @Luboš Turek I can't now. I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: @startupthekid I tried to change versions of ParseSDK now in my Podfile isn't the latest version but with the latest version (1.9.1) had same error output. So probably problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Just `rm -rf` the Pods folder, remove all the version dependencies (unless you really need a specific version) so that everything is `pod 'Parse'`, then run `pod install` again